# Синтаксис классов/структур c++

Tags: c++

Имеется такой класс для, например, вывода вектора через библиотеку algorithm.
Объясните по какому принципу myobject работает в коде и что это вообще такое?

```
struct myclass {          
void operator() (int i) {std::cout << ' ' << i;}
} myobject;


for_each (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject);
```

Comment: по принципу вызова оператора myclass::operator()(int),   для обьекта  myobject,  с аргументом  элемента вектора , в цикле , от  myvector.begin()  до  myvector.end()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Шаблонная функция `std::for_each` внутри себя пробегает в цикле по всему диапазону итераторов, который вы ей передали: от `myvector.begin()` до `myvector.end()` и для каждого итератора `it` в этом диапазоне выполняет следующее выражение

   ```
   myobject(*it)
   ```
2. Компилятор видит, что `myobject` - это не функция, а экземпляр некоего класса `myclass`. В такой ситуации компилятор расценивает выражение `myobject(*it)` как вызов

   ```
   myobject.operator()(*it)
   ```

   А это и есть вызов вашего метода класса с аргументом `*it`, т.е. с очередным значением из вектора.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере производится  вызов оператора `myclass::operator()(int`), для обьекта `myobject`, с аргументом элемента вектора , в цикле , `от myvector.begin()` до `myvector.end()`  (Пользователь `AnT` хорошо обьяснил...)

Поэтому, в цельях избежать вызова функции  `N` раз(где
     N == std::distance(myvector.begin(), myvector.end()) ),     для вывода лучше использовать более специализированные альгоритмы, например:

```
std::copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Тут отпадает необходимость определения функтора. Но, чтобы подчеркнуть преимущество альгоритма  `for_each`, который в итоге возвращает  свой аргумент функтор   `myobject`,  для примера добавим поле  в `myclass`, для хранения суммы элементов последовательности:

```
struct myclass {
    static int k;
    void operator() (int i) { k += i; std::cout << ' ' << i;}
} myobject;
int myclass::k = 0;
```

Теперь с каждым вызовом оператора, к  `myclass::k`  прибавится значение аргумента оператора. И `for_each` уже становится подходящей кандидатурой в  выборе альгоритма. И после:

```
for_each(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myobject); // вывод элементов
cout << endl << myobject.k; // вывод суммы элементов
```

Становится нагляднее  работа альгоритма и  ответ на ваш вопрос.

Мы будем иметь и вывод  и сохраним сумму элементов  `myvector` в   myclass::k. Конечно   `myclass`  может хранить и более ценные информации разного рода, а не тривиальную сумму элементов...

P.S. Не в тему, но если говорить об альгоритме `for_each`, то не только в таких случаях его целесообразно использовать. К примеру, можно  вызвать метод для каждого обьекта последовательности...